# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi red neuronal convolucional (cnn) aprenda cosas nuevas sin tener que volver a aprender todo lo que ya ha aprendido?

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la Inteligencia Artificial con python y tensorflow entre otros, y he programado una red neuronal convolucional (cnn) que clasifica entre perros gatos y gorilas, pero ahora quiero que aparte de esto también diferencie coches y motos, todo junto a estos 3 anteriores.
Entonces, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aprenda solamente a diferenciar entre estos dos nuevos casos sin tener que volver a aprender a diferenciar perros, gatos y gorilas? ya que son muchísimas imágenes y entrenar de nuevo esos 3 tipos le puede llevar horas, existe alguna forma de que solamente aprenda estos dos tipos nuevos?? este es mi código:

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers, layers, models
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()
data_train = './img/entrenamiento'
data_test = './img/test'

epochs = 20
steps_per_epoch = 1000
altura, longitud = 100, 100
batch_size = 32
steps_validation = 200
filtroConv1 = 32
filtroConv2 = 64
filtroConv1_size = (3,3)
filtroConv2_size = (2,2)
pool_size = (2,2)
tipos_imagen = 3
lr = 0.0005
train_labels = ['perro', 'gato', 'gorila']
test_labels = ['perro', 'gato', 'gorila']

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True
)

validacion_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255
)

train_images = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_train,
    target_size = (altura, longitud),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)

test_images = validacion_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_test,
    target_size = (altura, longitud),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)

cnn = models.Sequential()

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv1, filtroConv1_size, padding = 'same', input_shape = (altura, longitud, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv2, filtroConv2_size, padding = 'same'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))

cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(tipos_imagen, activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr), metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = cnn.fit(train_images, epochs = epochs, validation_data = test_images)

print(train_images.class_indices)

dir = './model/'

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir) 
    
cnn.save('./model/model.h5')
cnn.save_weights('./model/pesos.h5')
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer que aprenda ahora de nuevo con motos y coches, actualizando el modelo con sus pesos sin tener que volver a aprender todo? Muchas gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones, **reentrenar la red neuronal de nuevo** o hacer **Transfer Learning**, vamos a ver las dos:

## Entrenar la red neuronal de nuevo.

Sin duda esta es la mejor opción de todas, debido a que tu red neuronal no es muy pesada, tiene cuatro capas (quitando `Flatten`, `Dropout` y `Maxpool`) por lo que el tiempo no debería ser muy largo.

Probablemente tu tiempo sea largo porque la estás entrenando en la **CPU**, te recomiendo entrenarla en **GPU**, si tu ordenador no tiene, puedes usar [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb). Es totalmente gratuito y tu red neuronal tardará unos minutos. Tan solo tienes crear un nuevo Notebook de Jupyter e ir a las opciones `runtime -> change runtime type -> GPU`.

Anotar también que tendrás que subir tus directorios con imágenes a **Google  Colab**.

## Transfer Learning

Este método consiste en **congelar** las capas de tu red neuronal excepto la capa de salida (la última capa con la función `softmax`), se dice congelar porque dichas capas mantienen los pesos con los que han sido entrenados y no cambian y solo entrena tu última capa, con el aumento de clases que has realizado. Para realizarlo hacemos lo siguiente (te dejo comentario en el código):

```
#Borramos la última capa (ya que es la única que queremos entrenar)
del cnn.layers[-1]

#Congelamos todas las capas, para que no se entrenen
for capa in cnn.layers: capa.trainable = False

#Añadimos la última capa de predicciones, ahora son 5 unidades, porque hay dos clases más
cnn.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))

#Después compilamos el modelo y volvemos a entrenar como con cualquier red neuronal.
cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr), metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

## Bonus

- **Transfer Learning** se utiliza en redes neuronales con **Millones de parámetros**, son redes neuronales inmensas que necesitan ordenadores especiales muy potentes para ser entrenados. Como la comunidad de software abierto es muy grande, estas redes han sido entrenadas en estos ordenadores y pueden ser usadas por cualquiera. La idea detrás de esta técnica es que, **si una red neuronal con unos pesos es muy buena extrayendo características de las imágenes**, es porque extrae las características de las imágenes muy bien, y por tanto puedo utilizarla para clasificar otras imágenes.
- **Generador de imágenes**: un generador de imágenes siempre va a relentizar tu red neuronal, puesto que tiene que coger las imágenes, aplicar las transformaciones, y pasarla a la red neuronal. Si se utiliza `flow_from_directory()` porque **no puedes cargar todas las imágenes en RAM**, significa que tu ordenador tiene que coger los bloques de imágenes de uno en uno (32 imágenes por bloque en tu caso, que es el `batch_size`) del disco duro, pasarlas a la RAM y entrenar los pesos, después volver a coger el siguiente bloque y así. Esto es muy costoso computacionalmente, ya que **coger los bloques de imágenes del disco duro (de 32 en 32) es un proceso mucho más lento, que tenerlas directamente en la RAM**.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, en cuanto a lo de jupyter, donde está lo del runtime?? no logro encontrarlo.

Comment: Tienes que entrar en el link de Google Colab y en la pestaña `file` (arriba a la izquierda) encontrarás `New Notebook`

Comment: pero para eso tengo que cambiar de programa verdad? no puedo cambiarlo desde el propio jupyter?

Comment: Claro Google Colab es un servicio en la Nube. Tu notebook de Jupyter no tienes eso. Si quieres entrenar en tu ordenador con GPU, primero tienes que saber si tu ordenador tiene GPU, en el caso de que la tenga y sea compatible con Tensorflow, tienes que [seguir la instalación de Tensorflow con GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias, en mi caso tengo una 2080, desde el propio código no le puedo indicar a tensorflow que use la gpu?

Comment: Lo hace automáticamente si tienes la instalación hecha como en el link de arriba con CUDA :). Si quieres saber si estás utilizando la GPU, ejecuta ```tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')```. Si te aparece una lista con tu GPU (algo así) ```[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]```, es que ya la estás utilizando, si por el contrario, es una lista vacia, significa que no estás usando Tensorflow GPU, por lo que desisntala Tensorflow y sigue el link que te he puesto arriba.

Comment: Por otro lado con una RTX 2080 tienes potencia suficiente para ejecutarlo en tu ordenador, no necesitas usar Google Colab. Por lo que ejecuta el proceso en tu ordenador

Comment: Y si quisiera añadir nuevas imágenes a la categoría de perro, como podría hacer esto sin que afectase al entrenamiento completo y hacer que solamente ajustase los pesos que ya tenía con las nuevas imágenes

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta completamente distinta a la que se ha realizado y no tiene nada que ver, por lo que para la limpieza del sitio te recomiendo que hagas una nueva pregunta. Además así permites que más personas puedan responderla :). Si nadie te la responde, no te preocupes, en cuanto tenga tiempo me comprometo a responderte.

Comment: Y cuanto más rápido debería de ir la cnn?? para saber si lo he configurado bien, muchas gracias.